# Insert a new value to element of array and move the rest of elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making a program that it will be able to add any numbers on an array and then it will be able to modify them (insert,delete).What I want to know is how to create a new value in an array without modifying anything.Just create the value and push all the rest to the next one.Example: insert 1 8 //insert is just the command,1 is the place where you want to create the new value and 8 is the value itself so list[1] = 8 but I want the rest values that already exist to go 1 forward(if they are in the place I want to create the new value or higher than it(talking about place in the list))

Full example:
List:

```
5
6
7
8
9
```

Command: insert 3 10
New list:

```
5
6
7
10 //the one that changed,the rest from this point went 1 forward 
8
9
```

Comment: So, you have to write a linked list, or use containers. What is the question?

Comment: The question is how can I insert an element inside the array in a specific index (position) and place the rest of the values in the array for 1 value more. Look at the example for more details.

Comment: the answer is : like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Comment: Are talking about a command line tool here (this is what your example suggests, to be used with a syntax like `insert 1 8`), or do you just want to write a C++ function?

Comment: Either use a `vector` and [`vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), or append the element and do a [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) or do a [`std::copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) and then insert the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to use a `std::vector<int>` something like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
v.insert(v.begin() + 1, 8);   // v[1] now equals 8, everything after push up one
v.erase(v.begin() + 1);       // v is now as it was before above insert
v.insert(v.begin() + 3, 10);  // v[3] is now 10
```

Comment: `error: in C++98 'v' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'|` and `error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'|`

Comment: @user2699298 Use a C++11 compliant compiler.

Comment: I need solution for old version (not C++11) sorry if I didn't say that.

Comment: @user2699298 Just don't use the list-initialization. `std::vector<int> v; for(int i = 5; i < 10; ++i) v.push_back(i);`

Answer (score 2):

Let ***a*** be the array, ***position*** be the index in array where the value has to be inserted, and ***value*** be the value itself.

Then try:

```
int i;
for(i=CURRENT_SIZE_OF_ARRAY-1; i>=positon; --i)
{
   a[i+1] = a[i];
}
a[i]=value;
```

This way, you shift the array values from the end in order to make space for the new element, and then finally insert that element in the desired location.

Comment: Although if the array is full of values you want to keep, the last item in the array will be overwritten.

Comment: @splrs That is the drawback if one goes with arrays. They are of fixed size, and cannot be dynamically allocated more memory. This answer pertains to the user query wherein he is keen to use arrays only (see the tag). Otherwise std::vector is the best and easiest choice to implement this.

Comment: The loop essentially is a [`std::copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward), although that has a slightly awkward syntax here: `copy_backward(begin(a)+position, begin(a)+CURRENT_SIZE_OF_ARRAY, 1 + begin(a)+CURRENT_SIZE_OF_ARRAY);`

Comment: @DyP I'm not aware of std::copy_backward. I'll check it out; thanks for teaching me something new :)

Comment: Hm.. is a[i]=value outside the loop? If so, i will be undeclared I think in this case, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user2699298 Thanks for pointing it out! Corrected the code accordingly. Hope it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `std::vector` and `insert()`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/

Edit: unless you can't use STL containers and there's a requirement to use c-style arrays, in which case it won't be as straightforward, as you won't be able to directly grow them.